# Posting a form with a table, each row with multiple inputs, without Javascript

Tags: html, forms

This is partially an academic question, but I think it can be done properly without javascript, and I like to keep javascript out of the handling of form data when possible.

Let's say I have single text input called "Name", and a table that has an arbitrary number of rows.  Each row has two inputs in it, named "Color" and "Shape".

Let's say the text input is filled out as "Shape-Set-1" and there are 3 rows with the following values for Color and Shape:

- "Blue" and "Square"
- "Green" and "Circle"
- "Yellow" and "Triangle"

When I post, the POST data will look like this:

- Name: "Shape-Set-1"
- Color: "Blue"
- Color: "Green"
- Color: "Yellow"
- Shape: "Square"
- Shape: "Circle"
- Shape: "Triangle"

Great!  All the data made it!  But how do I know FOR SURE which Color and which Shape are connected?   Are they always guaranteed to be gathered in the correct order? (My guess is no, as it probably depends on the browser, unless there is a standard for this).  Is there a way to nest and have the rows report their Color and Shape inputs within an object?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give each row an id, so that the inputs become Colour1 and Shape1, Colour2 and Shape2, etc, then you can parse the keys on the server side, determining the number to allow you to link the two together.

I dont know how forms go about serializing their data and passing it across, if it is guaranteed that inputs will appear in order then you know that the Colour array and Shape array index 0 will relate to the same item (I do not know if this is the case though, might be worth looking into).